# Is is possible to force upgrdae database with sqflite flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) in my flutter application. It has database schema migration feature. I don't want that. I want to completely replace the existing database with the newer database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one solution using the existing migration mechanism would be to update the version, mark your database as 'to be re-created' during `onUpgrade`, then delete the db and re-create it.

Something like this:

```dart
Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
  // ... create your database
}
var shouldCreate = false;
var db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 2, onCreate: _onCreate,
    onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) {
  if (oldVersion < 2) {
    // Need to recreate the db
    shouldCreate = true;
  }
});
if (shouldCreate) {
  await db.close();
  await deleteDatabase(dbPath);
  db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 2, onCreate: _onCreate);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this deletes all data in the database